# Yahoo messenger API for Java

Tags: java

I want to connect to Yahoo messenger through a Java API.  I'm using the jYMSG API, but now I'm not able to connect to Yahoo messenger as I'm getting the error "Use updated version".  I'm using the jYMSG 6 API.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Just googling for "jymsg" seems to suggest that the current version is about 10.  This is also consistent with the error message.  You should do what it says: use a newer version.

Comment: I m not able to find new jar file

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [jymsg homepage](http://jymsg9.sourceforge.net/), click the "Downloads" link on the left side and there's a file called "ymsg_code_jars_v0_64.zip" which I assume contains the JAR's you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo changed the messenger protocol and jYMSG API seems to be a dead project.

Look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/openymsg/ which is a fork of jYMSG.

Comment: Thanks Zappi,i even tried openymsg,but i m not able to connect t yahoo messenger from openymsh.please help hw to solve.i m getting error illegal argument.

Comment: there are several threads in the openymsg forum that could be helpful